# How to create object of class inside function in function.php of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-sheets-api, php-5.5

I am integrating google spreadsheet in my project.  I have to save form data into google spreadsheet.
For this i am using asimqt [php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) library.

I have single form on site that form is submitting using ajax. For this i have written function in function.php.

Getting error when initializing object of DefaultServiceRequest class.

**Error:** Fatal error: Class 'Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest' not found

```
require '/vendor/autoload.php';

use  Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use  Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;


function spreadsheet_feeds()
{
    $access_tok = 'xyz-token';

    $serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($access_tok); // Getting error
    ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

    $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
    $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_spreadsheet_data', 'spreadsheet_feeds' );
add_action('wp_ajax_spreadsheet_data','spreadsheet_feeds');
```

Any help why this error is occurring because class is already include using "use" statement ?

Comment: please paste a screenshot of where you have uploaded that php-google-spreadsheet-client library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the location of your `vendor` folder.
Make sure that the vendor folder is accessible by the file

Considering your folder hierarchy to be

```
-wp-content
--themes
---your-theme
----functions.php
```

If you have your vendor folder in `your-theme/vendor` then in your functions.php

you should write

`require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

and if `vendor` is in the root directory of WP make sure you traverse back to the root folder using something like :

`require __DIR__ .'/../../../../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: Vendor folder is located inside theme folder. I have tried with require 'vendor/autoload.php'; but same error is occuring.

Comment: @Kango I have tried with the same library and with vendor folder in the my-theme directory and it is working fine,  try using `composer dump-autoload` in your themes folder

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `require '/vendor/autoload.php';` to `require_once('vendor/autoload.php');`

Just now I tried this here for you myself and it works.